# How to activate CSS :hover events in a touch only browser?

Tags: jquery, browser, touch-event, jquery-hover, touchmove

Since `:hover` is of course not supported in touch only browsers.

Also some CSS `:hover` events can be activated through a touch only browser if you hold your finger on the screen.

I want working `touchmove` with `:hover` css.

Does anyone have solution to working `:hover` in touch only browser?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there's no hover on touch devices.

A longer answer can be found in the following article:
https://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event Listener to touchstart , touchend and then add a class to element whenever touch event is fired on that element. You can then apply all the hover effects on touch with the help of newly added class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').on('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_touch');
    });
});
```

Then in your css files do the following:

```
element:hover, element.hover_touch{
    rule : property:
}
```

Comment: I have also `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event parallel to `touchmove` and `touchend`.